# JavaScript improper object structure - extract whats possible

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have data structure as below

```
{ 
status: false, 
executed: true, 
output : "Service is under maintenance [ {"command" :"uptime", "output" :"connection timeout"}] - exit status 3
}
```

I am trying to extract `[ { "command" :"uptime", "output" :"connection timeout" }]` from above data structure. if it is clean it be using regular dot walking with parse.

As this is not in proper format, I am looking for suggestions only to extract valid data structure.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the text "Service is under maintenance" a string?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe Yes, it is a string.

Comment: Does the entire thing come into your program as a string?

Comment: @JoshWulf, yes, Entire output will come in string format. For now parsing external object and using "includes" to find success or failure.

Answer (score 2):

use `indexOf("[")` and `lastIndexOf("]")` to substring the string then use `JSON.parse` to parse the jsonstring ,then you will get `[ { "command" :"uptime", "output" :"connection timeout" }];`

hope it would help you

Comment: To be honest, your idea make sense. :‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

You can use string split functions in JavaScript to split the output string and then Parse the JSON String as a valid JSON. Hope the below code will help you.

```js
var inputJson ={ 
  status: false, 
  executed: true, 
  output : 'Service is under maintenance [ {"command" :"uptime", "output" :"connection timeout"}] - exit status 3'
}

var outputJson = JSON.parse(inputJson.output.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]);
console.log(outputJson.output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `output` is a string from *Service* to *status 3*...

Here is a function to "clean" your data. I added a condition in case the data isn't "messed" ;)

```js
let messedData = {
  status: false,
  executed: true,
  output: 'Service is under maintenance[{"command": "uptime","output": "connection timeout"}] - exit status 3 '
}

function clean(data){
  
  if(typeof(data.output) === "string"){
    data.output = JSON.parse(data.output.match(/\[.+\]/)[0])
  }
  return data
}

console.log(clean(messedData))
```